# what to change in my visual basic code to display the sum in decimal with comma format

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to display the sum with comma and a decimal but using this code I am only able to display the first 2 digits of the sum, kindly help me fix it. Thanks.

```
Private Sub btnsum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsum.Click
    Dim sum
    Dim a
    Dim b
    Dim c
    a = Val(lblnum1.Text)
    b = Val(lblnum2.Text)
    c = Val(lblnum3.Text)
    sum = (a + b + c)
    lblsum.Text = Format(sum, "#,###,##0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: `lblSum.Text = sum.ToString("N")`

Comment: Thanks but it says "InvalidCastException was unhandled"

Comment: Recommend to use `Option Strict On` and fix the resulting errors.  If you declare your variables in the same statement where you assign them (e.g. `Dim a = Val(lblnum1.Text)`) and have `Option Infer On` (which I believe it is by default) you won't need to explicitly provide the variable types.

Answer (score 0):

```
lblsum.text = sum.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Don't forget to insert

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this format
`lblsum.Text = Format(sum, "#,##0.00")`